# Applying stereotype to property as association end throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: uml, emf

The same question I have asked at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/367608/

I want to apply a stereotype which is defined for UML-Property to a property used in an association. The problem I have is that an IllegalArgumentException is thrown in the case of using the stereotype for an association-associated property. If I apply the stereotype to an property which is used in a class as an attribute everything is fine.

Here is a code snippet from the exception throwing part:

```
helper def: getStereotype(name: String): UML!Stereotype =
UML!Stereotype.allInstancesFrom('PRO') -> select(p | p.name = name) -> first();
-- ...
p1: UML!Property(

    upper <-a.associationEnds.first().conformance.upperBound,
    lower <- a.associationEnds.first().conformance.lowerBound,
    name <- a.associationEnds.first().name,
    type <- firstMemberType,
    opposite <- p2,
    isComposite <- true
),

p2: UML!Property(

        upper <-a.associationEnds.last().conformance.upperBound,
        lower <- a.associationEnds.last().conformance.lowerBound,
        name <- a.associationEnds.last().name,
        type <- secondMemberType,
        opposite <- p1
    ),

as:UML!Association(
        name <- a.name,
        ownedEnd <- Set{p2}
        navigableOwnedEnd <- Set{p1}
        )
    do {
p1.applyStereotype(thisModule.getStereotype('xsdElement')); -- here an exception is thrown: see below
}
```

The following IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

```
Here appear some other resulting stacktraces.
......

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.StereotypeImpl@21ee05 (name: xsdElement, visibility: <unset>) (isLeaf: false, isAbstract: false) (isActive: false)
    at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.operations.ElementOperations.applyStereotype(ElementOperations.java:1413)
    at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.ElementImpl.applyStereotype(ElementImpl.java:510)
    ... 18 more
```

I've used `UML=http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML`.

It seems like that p1 is not a property any longer. Anyone an idea? Would be great. thanks,
Martin

**EDIT1:**

After doing some debugging, I've found that the call of the method in the flow is first successful. Until the method finalizeModel is called, everthing is fine. When the method finalizeModel in the ATL UML2ModelAdapter is called the stack trace is thrown:

```
Java Stack:
org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.VMException
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.adapter.UML2ModelAdapter.finalizeModel(UML2ModelAdapter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.lib.ExecEnv.terminated(ExecEnv.java:2557)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.ASM.run(ASM.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.launch.EMFVMLauncher.internalLaunch(EMFVMLauncher.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.launch.EMFVMUILauncher.launch(EMFVMUILauncher.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.core.service.LauncherService.launch(LauncherService.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.core.ui.launch.AtlLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launchOrDebug(AtlLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.core.ui.launch.AtlLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(AtlLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.adapter.UML2ModelAdapter.applyDelayedInvocations(UML2ModelAdapter.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.m2m.atl.engine.emfvm.adapter.UML2ModelAdapter.finalizeModel(UML2ModelAdapter.java:49)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.StereotypeImpl@580b29 (name: xsdElement, visibility: <unset>) (isLeaf: false, isAbstract: false) (isActive: false)
    at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.operations.ElementOperations.applyStereotype(ElementOperations.java:1413)
    at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.ElementImpl.applyStereotype(ElementImpl.java:510)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

The issue was, that I had applied the profile to a subordinated package and not to the root package. I had added the associations to the root package. So every try to apply stereotypes to the root-package failed, because it hadn't no knowledge of my profile.

So the application of the property-associated stereotype only crashed when properties were part of associations. Properties that are representing class attributes were in the subordinated packages.

I also have posted the answer at: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/367608/